# How can I make useEffect() optional based on props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I would like to have a component named Row that displays a row of movies. Some would have to be fetched and others that are my custom picks would be passed in as props so no fetching required.

I'm passing in the fetchUrl for those that will make a call. But for the ones that are custom I will pass in a array of options. I would like to have this useEffect to make the calls but its not necessary when I pass in the custom picks.

```
 useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          const request = await axios({ url: fetchUrl, baseURL: BASE_URL });
          setMovies(request.data.results);
        }
        fetchData();
      }, [fetchUrl]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The hooks themselves should be called conditionally - see [Only Call Hooks at the Top Level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). However, the code inside the hook can. Wrap the code inside the `useEffect()` in a condition - only fetch data if there's a url:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(fetchUrl) {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios({
        url: fetchUrl,
        baseURL: BASE_URL
      });
      setMovies(request.data.results);
    }
    fetchData();
  }
}, [fetchUrl]);
```

If you need to set the custom movie as well, you can do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (fetchUrl) {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios({
        url: fetchUrl,
        baseURL: BASE_URL
      });
      setMovies(request.data.results);
    }
    fetchData();
  } else if (customMovies) {
    setMovies(movies => [...movies, ...customMovies]); // add custom movies to current movies
  }
}, [fetchUrl, customMovies]);
```